# Unable to found if a Point is inside a Polygon with GeoSparqrl and sfWithin function

Tags: sparql, jena, geosparql

I'm need to write a query to check if a determined Point is inside a Polygon.

I'm trying to use GeoSparql, but isn't producing the expected results.

If I execute a simple query, like it:

```
PREFIX iot-lite: <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/UNIS/fiware/iot-lite#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>

SELECT ?poligono ?pointGeo
    WHERE{
    ?casa  iot-lite:hasPoint ?poligono ;
            rdf:type iot-lite:Polygon .
    ?point  rdf:type  geo:Point ;
            iot-lite:hasPoint ?pointGeo .  
}
```

The results are:

```
?poligon
    "POLYGON((-16.67362 -49.24468, -16.67363 -49.24466, -16.67365 -49.24468, -16.67364 -49.2447, -16.67364 -49.24468))"^^<http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#wktLiteral>

?pointgeo    
    "POINT((-16.67363 -49.24468))"^^<http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#wktLiteral>
```

But if i add the filter below to the query, it return nothing. But the problem is: the point is within the polygon

```
FILTER (geof:sfWithin(?pointGeo, ?poligono))
```

Answer (score 1):

Jena doesn't implement GeoSPARQL.
See the [documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/spatial-query.html#property-function-library) for the Jena specific spatial functions.

Comment: Either when I run this query at CloudDB the results are the same.  Why? It's not a Jena implementation, so it should works, right?

Comment: Don't know CloudDB but it would depend on what software they use to implement their SPARQL endpoint. GeoSparql support is far from universal.

Comment: @MaykeFerreira what is CloudDB, where does it support SPARQL? and why do you assume that nay triple store supports GeoSPARQL? It's not part of the W3C SPARQL specs...

Comment: by the way it is not so difficult to make support that Geosparql in jena, at least for that function: need just implement `org.apache.jena.sparql.function.Function` and register namespace 'geof:sfWithin' in the jena-system. Maybe there are already ready-made solutions in github or somewhere else.

Comment: @ssz  do you have any idea how i can link a prefix geof:sfWithin with their respective method implementation?? I ask it, because I found some examples, and the link is made between the prefix and a java method, and, in this case, I don't have access to sfWithin function.

Comment: need to link full uri (not just prefixed form) with java-body. See `org.apache.jena.sparql.function.StandardFunctions` how it is made for xpath-functions (namespaces `fn` and `math`).

Comment: Hello....Is it possible to use geosparql in Python as mentioned like above in Java ?